# Gremlin: adding edges between nodes having the same property

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop, edges, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am very new to Gremlin. I am trying to build a graph on DSE graph using Gremlin. I am able to create the vertices:

```
a = graph.addVertex(label, 'label1', 'key', 1)
b = graph.addVertex(label, 'label1', 'key', 2)
c = graph.addVertex(label, 'label2', 'key', 1)
d = graph.addVertex(label, 'label2', 'key', 2)
```

Now i am looking to  automatically add edges between two nodes with differents label where the property 'key' matches (i.e create and edge between a and c, and between b and c). I am stuggling to do that.

I tried to do the following

```
 g.V().hasLabel("label1").sideEffect{g.V().("label2").has("key",it.key).addEdge("link",it)}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
No signature of method: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.traverser.B_O_Traverser.values() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [key]
```

Can somebody assists me on this issue ?
Thank you by advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested `g.V()`'s are usually a bad idea. You can solve the problem using a single traversal:

```
g.V().hasLabel("label1").as("a").
  V().hasLabel("label2").as("b").
  where("a", eq("b")).by("key").
  addE("link").from("a").to("b")
```

Also note that you'll have to allow scans in DSE Graph to make this traversal work.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was exactly what is was looking for and it helped me a lot!