# igraph in R: Add edges between vertices with shared attributes

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to create a graph in R using igraph based on rules. I have a graph with nodes, each of which has several attributes. I'd like to add edges based on those attributes. Toy example:

```
library(igraph)
make_empty_graph() %>% 
  add_vertices(
    nv = 5, 
    attr = list(
      this_attr = sample(c("a", "b"), 5, replace = TRUE)
    )
  ) %>%
{something here to add edges where this_attr is the same)
```

This appears to be a solution if I were using Gremlin in Python, but I don't grok it/igraph enough to translate to igraph: [Gremlin: adding edges between nodes having the same property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163563/gremlin-adding-edges-between-nodes-having-the-same-property)

If tidygraph would make this easier, that'd be an acceptable dependency.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: This works but feels super messy.

```
g <- igraph::make_empty_graph() %>% 
  igraph::add_vertices(
    nv = 5, 
    attr = list(
      sample_attr = sample(c("a", "b"), 5, replace = TRUE)
    )
  )

g %>% 
  igraph::vertex_attr() %>% 
  unname() %>% 
  purrr::map(
    function(this_attribute) {
      unique(this_attribute) %>% 
        purrr::map(
          function(this_value) {
            utils::combn(
              which(this_attribute == this_value), 2
            ) %>% 
              as.integer()
          }
        ) %>% unlist()
    }
  ) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  igraph::add_edges(g, .)
```

Something similar but cleaner would be fantastic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I don't think *igraph* has anything as succinct as the **gremlin** example in which a general statement of `connect any vertex (A) with any vertex (B) if they share an attribute` However, **R** provides a bunch of ways to do this with matrices (as @Julius showed) and data frames. Below is how I'd go about this problem with igraph and R.

Given the following graph:

```
set.seed(4321)
g <- make_empty_graph() %>% 
       add_vertices(nv = 5, attr = list(sample_attr = sample(c("a", "b"), 5, replace = TRUE)))
```

We can make a data frame with information taken from the vertices and then `left_join` it to itself using the attribute column. I'm assuming direction doesn't matter here and that we want to get rid of duplicates. If that is the case, then simply `filter` the node columns using a `<` operator.

```
edge_list <- data.frame(
  #id = V(g)$name #if it has a name.....
  id = 1:vcount(g), #if no name exists, then then the order of a vertex represents an id
  attr = V(g)$sample_attr #the first item in this vector corresponds to the first vertex/node
) %>%
  dplyr::left_join(., .,  by = 'attr') %>% #join the data frame with itself
  dplyr::filter(id.x < id.y)  #remove self pointing edges and duplicates
  # 1 %--% 2 equals 2 %--% 1 connection and are duplicates
```

Once we have information the edge list in a data frame, we need to convert the pair of node columns into a pairwise vector. This can be done by converting the columns into a matrix, transposing the matrix so that the rows are now columns, then converting the matrix into a single (pair-wise) vector.

```
edge_vector <- edge_list %>% 
  dplyr::select(id.x, id.y) %>% #select only the node/vertex columns
  as.matrix %>% #convert into a matrix so we can make a pairwise vector
  t %>% #transpose matrix because matrices convert to vectors by columns
  c #now we have a pairwise vector
```

Now, all we need to do is add the pairwise vector and the associated attributes to the graph.

```
g <- add_edges(g,
               edge_vector, 
               attr = list(this_attr = edge_list$attr))  #order of pairwise vector matches order of edgelist
```

Let's plot this to see if it worked.

```
set.seed(4321)
plot(g, 
     vertex.label = V(g)$sample_attr, 
     vertex.color = ifelse(V(g)$sample_attr == 'a', 'pink', 'skyblue'),
     edge.arrow.size = 0)
```

[image]

Another potential solution is to start with a data frame instead of an empty graph. The data frame would represent a node list that we can join to itself and create an edge list.

```
set.seed(4321)
node_list <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                        attr= sample(c('a', 'b'), 5, replace = T))

edge_list <- merge(node_list, node_list, by = 'attr') %>% #base R merge
  .[.$id.x < .$id.y, c('id.x', 'id.y', 'attr')]  #rearrange columns in base so first two are node ids 

g <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edge_list, directed = F, vertices =  node_list) 

set.seed(4321)
plot(g, 
     vertex.label = V(g)$attr, 
     vertex.color = ifelse(V(g)$attr == 'a', 'pink', 'skyblue'),
     edge.arrow.size = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a graph,

```
g <- make_empty_graph() %>% 
  add_vertices(nv = 5, attr = list(this_attr = sample(c("a", "b"), 5, replace = TRUE)))
```

we can first define this adjacency matrix in terms of the attribute

```
(auxAdj <- tcrossprod(table(1:gorder(g), V(g)$this_attr)) - diag(gorder(g)))  
#     1 2 3 4 5
#   1 0 1 1 1 0
#   2 1 0 1 1 0
#   3 1 1 0 1 0
#   4 1 1 1 0 0
#   5 0 0 0 0 0
```

and use it to add edges as in

```
g <- add_edges(g, c(t(which(auxAdj == 1, arr.ind = TRUE))))
```

where

```
c(t(which(auxAdj == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)))
# [1] 2 1 3 1 4 1 1 2 3 2 4 2 1 3 2 3 4 3 1 4 2 4 3 4
```

meaning the we want edges (2,1), (3,1), (4,1) and so on.